What is the probability that some card will end up as the top 10 $k$ times after $n$ shuffles?
I'm trying to calculate the probability that after, $n$ shuffles, some card ends up within the top 10 places $k$ times. I think I have got the answer, but I think I might be missing something.
So with a 52 card deck, a given card landing on the top 10 in a given shuffle would have probability $p=10/52$. And for several ($n$) shuffles, getting the top ten $k$ times follows a binomial distribution
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
n\\
k
\end{matrix}
\right)
p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
$$
Then, calculating the probability of some card ending up in this spot $k$ times is where I'm feeling dubious. My first instinct would be to just multiply by the number of cards. Would this be wrongly assuming independence between the outcomes of cards after $n$ shuffles? Does it matter if they are or aren't independent?
